# Install Windows 8 on other partition from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, windows-8-preview

Is it possible to install Windows 8 on another partition from Windows 7 (not from the boot menu but from within Windows itself)?

Answer (score 1):

1) **using diskpart**

Format the partition to NTFS Quick format

Extract windows8.iso to the new partition

open CMD as Administrator

Enter the following commands, (replace X with what applies to your hard drive):

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk X
list partition
select partition X
active
exit
X:\boot\bootsect.exe /nt60 X:
```

Exit and reboot

Install Windows as usual

2) **Using easybcd**

Download and install easyBCD

run easyBCD

Go to **Add new entry** select **iso** and the path to your iso file
Clic **add new entry**

Next step , **edit boot menu** and select windows 8 64 bit

Extract windows8.iso to the new partition

Reboot

Install Windows as usual

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible. `Because some guy had installed WIN8 on other disk, so there are dual system on the computer`. Just try but as far as I know, it will be much trouble if you want to remove Win8 from your computer without affecting WIN7. Not sure

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can install the windows-8 within the windows-7. Because I have installed Windows-7 within Windows XP it was working like a charm. Just you have to make sure your system drive I mean be sure on which partition you have to install the windows-8. If there is same size partition then you can change the size of partition to recognize the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do so… At least I didn't want to risk a working Windows 7 system.

When you run Windows 8 setup from other version of Windows, there are three options:

- Save Windows parameters, personal files and applications
- Save only my personal files
- Save nothing

The first two options really mean *upgrade*. I wasn't sure enough to try the third option. I understand the third option is to replace the existing OS with the newly installed Windows 8.

I tried to find information on the Internet about it but I wasn't much successful. However, one of the step-by-step guides, clearly mentioned:

> You have to boot from Windows 8 DVD or USB to perform a clean boot.

That's what I did. I installed it on the 2nd partition of the hard drive, and it gives me the option to boot to Windows 8 or the previous version of Windows.